# JavaScript Array Comparison (aka Set Comparison)

Tags: javascript, array

I want to compare the values in two arrays. The order of the values doesn't matter. Basically they are two Sets. This function returns true if the values are the same in both arrays, or false otherwise.

```
function compareSets(a1, a2) {
    if (a1.length !== a2.length) {
        return false;
    }

    var len = a1.length;
    var a1Set = {};

    // Convert a1 into a Set
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        var value1 = a1[i];
        a1Set[value1] = true;
    }

    // Compare a2 values to a1 values
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        var value2 = a2[i];
        if (!(value2 in a1Set)) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

This is an \$O(n)\$ solution which is better than the naive \$O(n^2)\$. I think it is always safe to say that if the lengths are different, the arrays are not the same.

Is there any way I can make this more concise?

Comment: You could use [actual `set` functionality like here](https://github.com/jfriend00/Javascript-Set/blob/master/set.js) which has an `.equals()` and `.diff()` method and others for comparing two sets.  More info [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7958292/mimicking-sets-in-javascript/7958422#7958422)  in this stackoverflow answer.

Comment: `a1Set[value1] = true;` this solution is less correct than the *naive?* solution of storing values in an array and using index of as it won't work for non primitives (e.g. try comparing `[{1: 'a', 2: 'b'}]` with `[{}]` as you're storing the string representation of the object

Comment: We generally don't allow code in questions to be edited in a way that invalidates existing answers. (The more appropriate action would have been to tag the question as [tag:typescript] instead.) Normally, I'd revert such edits, but I'll let this one slide.

Comment: What if the arrays have repeated elements? With your function, `['a', 'a', 'b']` would be considered equal to `['a', 'b', 'b']`, but not equal to `['a', 'b']`. Also, letting `var x = ['a', 'a'], y = ['a', 'b'];`, we get `compareSets(x, y) == false` but `compareSets(y, x) == true`.

Comment: This aint concise and dont think its O(n) or woteva that is, I just wanted to see if I could make one that actually works ;)....
http://jsbin.com/coweb/1/edit
...tried to take into account what @200_success said as well.

Comment: @PAEz That implementation might be worth posting as a Code Review question.

Comment: @200_success  hehe, maybe...except I would only really have one question and thats if you can make it faster (I REALLY dont care about small code) and then Id have to unroll the every and reduce and as Im not ever going to use this (was just curious) it all seems a lot of effort for nothing ;)
But if anyone else did Ill admit Id like to see it....maybe later

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In JavaScript objects, keys are always strings, or converted into strings.  Therefore, all the elements of `a1` and `a2` will be compared as if they were stringified.  For example, `compareSets(['true'], [true])` returns `true`.  I consider that to be unexpected behaviour that either needs to be fixed or documented.

Comment: Furthermore, you have to be careful about the order of keys in an object. For example, `{x:1,y:2}` is equivalent to `{y:2,x:1}`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use one loop and compare each other on each iteration. You can use `indexOf` to check for one value on the other.

```
function compareSets(a1, a2) {
  //length check (you said it was safe to assume different lengths is not the same set)
  if (a1.length !== a2.length) return false;

  // Contents check
  var len = a1.length;
  while(len--){
    // If value at index doesn't exist in the other
    // indexOf returns -1 for a non-existent value and !~ turns -1 to true
    // If either one returns a -1 anywhere in the routine, break away immediately
    if(!~a2.indexOf(a1[len]) || !~a1.indexOf(a2[len])){
      return false;
    }
  }

  // All exist with each other, return true
  return true;
}
```

Comment: As far as I know, array.indexOf is a O(n) operation so this solution is O(n^2).